# Win32: limited movement of the child windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi, masm, masm32

I have for example 9 child windows. Now each of them I can move in any direction within the parent window. But I want the one in the middle moved only left, right, up and down (but not diagonally!!!) and automatically aligned to the center. I can't figure out how to implement it. Any help is appreciated. Even in `C/C++`. Or in words - just explanation.

[image: limited movement of the child windows]

That's how I process the movement of child windows:

```
.elseif [iMsg] == WM_LBUTTONDOWN

    invoke SetCapture, [hwnd]

    invoke InvalidateRect, [hwnd], 0, TRUE

    xor eax, eax
    ret

.elseif [iMsg] == WM_LBUTTONUP

    invoke ReleaseCapture

    xor eax, eax
    ret

.elseif [iMsg] == WM_MOUSEMOVE

    .if [wParam] & MK_LBUTTON

        movsx eax, word ptr [lParam]
        mov [x], eax
        movsx eax, word ptr [lParam+2]
        mov [y], eax

        invoke GetChildCenter, [hwnd], addr center_x, addr center_y

        mov eax, [x]
        sub eax, CELL_CENTER
        add [center_x], eax

        mov eax, [y]
        sub eax, CELL_CENTER
        add [center_y], eax

        invoke MoveChildByCenter, [hwnd], [center_x], [center_y]

    .endif

    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

MoveChildByCenter

```
MoveChildByCenter proc hwnd:HWND, x:dword, y:dword

    sub [x], CELL_CENTER
    sub [y], CELL_CENTER
    invoke MoveWindow, [hwnd], [x], [y], CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT, TRUE

    ret

MoveChildByCenter endp
```

GetChildCenter (relative to the parent window)

```
GetChildCenter proc hwnd:HWND, x:ptr dword, y:ptr dword

    local rect:RECT
    local parent:HWND
    local point:POINT
    invoke GetWindowRect, [hwnd], addr rect

    mov eax, [rect].left
    mov [point].x, eax
    add [point].x, CELL_WIDTH/2
    mov eax, [rect].top
    mov [point].y, eax
    add [point].y, CELL_HEIGHT/2

    invoke GetParent, [hwnd]
    mov [parent], eax

    invoke ScreenToClient, [parent], addr point

    mov ecx, [x]
    mov eax, [point].x
    mov [ecx], eax
    mov ecx, [y]
    mov eax, [point].y
    mov [ecx], eax

    ret

GetChildCenter endp
```

Comment: If you can move up/down and left/right then you can move diagonally by simply doing one and then the other.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I can move diagonally and any other way, but I don't need it. I want only up/down and left/right

Comment: Firstly, define various testcases for movements that must succeed and those that must not succeed. Then, write a human-language description of the algorithm that does the movement. Verify the algorithm covers all  the testcases. Then, translate the algorithm to code and preferably the test cases to according unit tests.

Comment: @FionaP. you misunderstand what Jonathan is trying to tell you. I can move something diagonally by first moving it horizontally, then initiating a new move and moving it vertically. The diagonal "move" is the end product of two nondiagonal moves, forming a right triangle with the two moves as the legs and the diagonal as the hypotenuse. (This is how vector components work in mathematics.) Does each individual move affect the state of the other children? What type of interface are you making? Is this a game?

Comment: @andlabs thank you for your explanation. Yes, this is a game like "three in a row". I haven't thought of how child windows will communicate with the parent. Maybe I should use some `ChildWinNotifyStruct` with the coordinates and sign of valid movement and process it in `WndProcMain` in `WM_NOTIFY`

Comment: Are the children moved by drag and drop? If so, I suppose one alternative approach is to display an indicator when the piece moves within the vicinity of a valid space; if the mouse is released there, the piece will move there, and if the mouse is released elsewhere, the move is cancelled. Just an idea; much easier and less problematic than trying to restrict movement like this on a two-dimensional input mechanism.

Comment: @andlabs thank you. I'll think about it.

Comment: A possible approach is to set the smallest of x and y to the reference zero. I'm not sure what it is in your code but I mean something like `if [x]>[y] then [y] = CELL_CENTER; else [x] = CELL_CENTER;` just after `invoke GetChildCenter`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks a lot for your response. It helped a little bit, but I still can move child windows in any direction

Comment: You can try this: When you handle *WM_LBUTTONDOWN*, save the *x* and *y* (say in *oX* and *oY*) of the cursor. In *WM_MOUSEMOVE* use this new condition `if abs([x]-[oX]) > abs([y]-[oY]) then ...`. This should make the child jump (snap) to one the x-y axis.

Comment: @MargaretBloom ok, now I can't move child window up/down. Only left/right. But it's good that I can see at least some movement restrictions. Now I need to figure out how to implement it correctly. You really help me again) But If you come up with something else, please, share it.

Comment: And if I'll do like that: `if abs([x]-[oY]) > abs([y]-[oX]) then ...`, I can move up/down and not left/right. Now I need to limit movement to a certain number of pixels

Comment: @FionaP. Are you sure you implemented the test correctly? I can't figure out why it only works up/down or left/right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108085/discussion-between-fiona-p-and-margaret-bloom).